# Grails Get null value from stored instance in session

Tags: hibernate, grails, httpsession

I am working on grails. My requirement is to get an object in whole application per user till user's session is available. After start my application when I logging in as user,after that I put an object in session.

```
Object object = Object.findById(idName)
session.object = object
```

In controller when I need this object I just write this syntax.

```
Object object = session.object
```

also sometimes I get that object with this syntax.

```
Object object = Object.findById(session.object?.id)
```

sometimes they return exact object and sometimes it return null.
I am not getting where I am making mistake.

Comment: Definitely not a question that should receive upvotes. Unclear, additional questions led to contradiction in user1791574 statements, doesn't show any research effort!

Answer (score 0):

Session is tracked for each of application users - when you put something in the session of one user it's present only in his, other sessions remain intact.

From what you're saying, you want the object to be present application-wide. For that purpose, you could use servletContext - http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/servletContext.html.

In Bootstrap you can use it like this:

```
def init = { 
  servletContext ->

  Object object = Object.findById(idName)
  servletContext.setAttribute('myObject', object)
}
```

after that, object will be available in all controllers via

```
servletContext.getAttribute('myObject')
```

Comment: I do not want to object in whole application.I just need it for every user separately. I have edited my question. Please take a look.

Comment: Then the problem is obvious - how could you put the object into user sessions on application start? In that moment user sessions don't exist yet - session is created for a user when user accesses your application for the first time. I'll update my answer then.

Comment: I put object session after logging in user.

Comment: "I put object session after logging in user." and "when my application start, I put that object in session." seems to me like two contradicting informations. Could you post the class where you put object into session?

Comment: I have edited my question. Can you please take a look.